# Do survivors die if you don't immediately rescue them?

Tags: state-of-decay

Various times throughout the game, you'll receive a radio message indicating that a survivor is in trouble, or that there are possible survivors in an area.

If I choose to continue looting houses or doing other missions, will this have any effect on the number of people who survive?

Do survivors die if you don't immediately rescue them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I think the timeout for such mission is about 1 hour playing time (when you play the game. Offline time does not count). When the mission times out, it is randomly determined if the characters will survive or get injured/die.
- Before the timeout, if you don't wander around the vicinity of the mission area, the survivors won't be spawned yet. So it doesn't matter if you rescue them 5 minutes after getting the missions or 50 minutes, as long as you keep the zombies off them when they spawn.
- In the new Breakdown DLC, time out for these missions is a lot shorter (about 30 minutes or less)

Answer (score 1):

There is a ratio of death to survival if a survivor is in trouble. From my experience, when I leave the survivors, they usually come back to the base alive but I might lose 1 medicine resource and lose 1 morale point.